# Discord.js replace ID inside array with the nickname of the user matching that ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

```js
if (message.content === '.mutelist') {

        var muteIdsList = muteIds.slice();

        var memberList = message.guild.members.array();

        var convertList = muteIdsList.indexOf(`${memberList}`);

        console.log(`${memberList}`);

        if (convertList !== -1) {

            muteIdsList[convertList] = `${guild.member.nickname}`

            console.log('Match!')
        }

        message.channel.send(`${muteIdsList}`)
        .catch(function(err) {

            if (muteIds.length >= 0) {

                message.channel.send('Nobody is being muted at this time!');
            }

            else {

                message.channel.send('There was an unknown error that occured, try running the command again!');
            } 
        })
    }
```

Nothing seems to be working so far, memberList does what I want my by fetching all the user ID's in the guild, but displays them as <@ID> instead of just the plain ID and so it doesn't match any items inside the array I have. What I want to happen is, I made a copy of the array i'm using to hold ID's for people to be muted, then taking all the ID's in the guild, run through the copied array and find all matches, then replace the ID's inside the copied array with the nickname of the user matching that specific ID.

Comment: try to reduce the description of your problem to a minimal test case and question, thanks.

Comment: The description I gave was about as simplistic as I could make it without not explaining the problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the members to nicknames mapping by using message.guild.members.

```
    var muteIdsList = muteIds.slice(); // [1]
    var memberList = message.guild.members; // {1: nickname1, 2: nickname2}
    var mutedNicknameList = muteIdsList.map(x => memberList[x]); // [nickname1]
```

Comment: The data is just the array filled with any IDs the people add via running a command that takes the ID as an argument, that's all, but how would I go about creating a map  of the array and setting the values of those IDs with the nicknames?

Comment: Can you debug and show me how each of the lists look that you are getting from discord? Im still confused where you are getting the list of nicknames from and how that data looks.

Comment: I'm not getting a list of nicknames, i'm getting a list of all user ID's in the guild and matching them to the IDs in the array.

Comment: If you are not getting nicknames how are you going to match a user's id to their nickname?

Comment: That's what i'm not quite sure of, or even how to go about matching the ID's and getting the nicknames anyways.

Comment: Thanks man! It's greatly appreciated, i'm going to do some research into mapping arrays to see how this works! :D

Comment: So adding in your comment to the code and changing the code below to go with it, and when I mute a test account and then do .mutelist, I have it to where it console logs **mutedNicknameList** and it's logs a blank line.

Comment: Can you post a console.log of the muteIdsList and memberList?

Comment: muteIdsList responds with the list of IDs that have been muted like it should because it's a copy. However memberList returns `[object Map]`